# Check remote file size through fetched link in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, ruby-2.0

I was wondering if there was a way to check on the size of files you have a link to?

I have extracted the path to an image (with mechanize) from a site and want to put a condition on it that turns true or false depending on the file size.

```
page = Mechanize.new.get(http://www.someurl.com/).parser
image = page.search('//img[@id="img1"]/@src').text
```

Now, what I want to do is checking for the file size of `image`.
For a local file I could do something like `File.size` to get its size in bytes. Is there any way to check the size of `image`?

Comment: You can save the image locally and use `File.size` method on it.

Comment: I know that, but in that case I had to download thousands of images. So what I am looking for is a way to do that without making a local copy.

Comment: Could you give me the URL? I wanted to check there something,if possible?

Comment: I can't give you the original URL, but any image from any side should work fine.

Comment: ok.. I am trying with this link - http://www.ebay.in/sch/Mobile-Phones-/15032/i.html .. Good question although.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [Mechanize#head method](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html#method-i-head) will work:

```
image_size = Mechanize.new.head( image_url )["content-length"].to_i
```

HTTP `HEAD` requests are a lesser known cousin of HTTP `GET`, where the server is expected to respond with the same headers as if performing the GET request, but does not include the body. It is used often in web caching.

[More on HTTP HEAD](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/head.html)

Example taken from Mobile Phones/eBay (requested by Arup Rakshit)

```
start_url = 'http://www.ebay.in/sch/Mobile-Phones-/15032/i.html'
crawler = Mechanize.new
page = crawler.get( start_url ).parser
image_url = page.search('//img/@src').first.text
image_size = crawler.head( image_url )["content-length"].to_i
 => 4244
```

Comment: wow... give the documentation link please..Give one complete code using the url I have given in the comment... :) if you wish

Comment: You got my support(*+1*) although.

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you!